# Ubuntu(WSL)でnodeというプロセスがCPUを異常に使用する。

Tags: node.js, vscode, wsl

WSL用のUbuntuをインストールし、Visual Studio Codeの[Remote WSL](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode-remote.remote-wsl)拡張機能でUbuntuにアクセスしました。

topコマンドでプロセスを確認したところ、command欄がnodeとなっているプロセスが常にCPU100%付近になっています。

Ubuntuはクリーンな環境に近く、aptでupdateとg++のインストールを行ったのみで、他は特に触っていません。

自分はWSL、Linux初心者なのでよくわかりませんが、WSL上にnodejsはインストールされていないと思います。

nodeコマンドを打つと

```
Command 'node' not found, but can be installed with:

apt install nodejs
```

と表示されます。

原因と対処法をお願いします。

Comment: ```ps -efl``` を実行すると、どのプロセスが起動しているか分かります。

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/76303 に同様の現象が報告されています。※私の拙い英語力では読解できませんでした。